# One click unsubscribe, but asking the user if sure before commiting

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, unsubscribe

I was following this tutorial to make a one-click unsubscribe using AMPscript.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVUB-CWT96k&ab_channel=Datarati-ImplementationGuru

The only issue that I have is that I need to make it with two clicks:

Once the user clicks on the "Unsubscribe" link I want to direct him to a cloud page with his email displayed and ask if he is sure.
If he click on confrimation then unsub.

So far I was only able to make the user click on the link on the email and unsubscribe for the list, but I cant hold the process for confirmation.

If it's not possible that's okay, but just curious, I've seen multiple questions about this without answer.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Yes, it's possible to have a two-click unsubscribe process in place. And you are right, I've checked quickly and didn't find any answer regarding this.

So to help you and maybe others save some time, here is the full code in an article written by Adam Spriggs:

[Two-Click Unsubscribe with AMPscript](https://sprignaturemoves.com/two-click-unsubscribe-with-ampscript/)

Comment: This worked like a charm! Now I have to figure out how to fill the subscriber, batch and job id for it so I can make a list level unsubscribe. Thank you!